# PHP form adds row in Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

I am trying to INSERT data into a database from a PHP form. I have written the code below but I do not understand why everytime I refresh the form it adds a new row with the previously entered data into my Database.
If someone could help me fix this issue, please.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>

<body>  

<?php include 'config.php'; ?>


<?php


     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $addr = $_POST['addr'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];



    $query = "INSERT INTO `employee`(fname,lname,addr,phone) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$addr','$phone')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("problem inserting new product into database");



     }


    ?>
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <h3>Enter the data to Sign Up</h3>
    <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>

    <form action = "" method = "post">
    Name: <input type = "text" name = "fname">
    <span class=error>*</span><br>
    Surname: <input type="text" name="lname">
    <span class=error>*</span><br>
    Address: <input type = "text" name = "addr">
    <span class=error>*</span><br>
    Phone Number: <input type = "tel" name="phone"><br>

    <input type = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Real simple; you need to use a conditional `empty()` around all of your user inputs. Then add a header.

Comment: Btw, if you value your work and the data, use a prepared statement. You're bound to get hacked.

Comment: I take it you don't care about security then. Oh well, I just hope you don't come back to us and say that your database suddenly disappeared.

Comment: I just started learning so I was trying to do something simple at first until I got the hang of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you validate a form, you create POST values in th eheader of your page. If you reload your page which has just undergone an action, it will repeat itself.

Just after

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("problem inserting new product into database");
```

You can add

```
header('Location : nameofyourpage.php')
```

or

```
unset($_POST)
```

Comment: Yes, the "header..." option worked.

Comment: Even though this is somewhat of a solution, it won't help it much if any of the inputs are left empty.